# Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)

Tags: debian, curl

I'm trying to update to `node 7.x` through the terminal on my `raspberry pi` and I keep encountering this error. The command I'm using is:

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -
```

Running this command as root doesn't work so I tried to see if apt-get was being used by any other processes.

```
ps aux | grep apt
pi        1295  0.0  0.1   4272  1848 pts/0    S+   06:24   0:00 grep --color=auto apt
```

This is all I get. Ultimately, (although it was initially advised not to do so), I tried removing the files and running the command again.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock && sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Now neither one of these files no longer exists and I still receive the same error when trying to use curl. I also tried to kill that one process and I still get the error.

Comment: the process you get from ps is the grep process itself, if you relaunch you'll notice a different pid

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you sudo curl but not the bash call which call apt.
just run it fully as root, for example :

```
sudo su
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -
```

or you can do something like

```
wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x
chmod +x setup_7.x
sudo ./setup_7.x
```

Comment: You don't need sudo for curl. Just sudo bash: curl ... | sudo bash -

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `lock` file

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Then run the command as root or add `sudo -E` as follows :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a very similar issue in a Dockerfile, by adding 'sudo' after the pipe:

`RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x  | sudo bash -`