# apt update; apt install metasploit-framework

Tags: kali-linux

I cant update msf console in kali linux,how can i fix that ? I used this command

```
apt update; apt install metasploit-framework
```

and got this error

```
#E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385860/could-not-open-lock-file-var-lib-apt-lists-lock-open-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the `apt` commands as the root user.  Or use `sudo apt`.